# Is it possible to automatically accept all tracked changes in Overleaf?

Tags: overleaf

Is it possible to automatically accept all tracked changes in Overleaf? Currently, I am only able to accept changes one by one in the review tab.

It would also be useful to learn if you can automatically resolve all comments.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you considered directing your question to the Overleaf Helpdesk? I hear their LaTeX support staff is top-notch.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll try that.

Comment: Ctrl + A, Accept All option top right

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From the Overleaf Helpdesk:

> While there isn't an option to accept all changes across an entire
> project, you can accept all tracked changes in a section, or in an
> entire file, by selecting the section of text - the "Accept All" and
> "Reject All" options will appear in the Review pane - this will appear
> near the top of the selected section.
>
> Because these options appear near the top of the section, it can
> happen that these options become hidden if you have the Track Changes
> menu expanded (it might be behind the dropdown list). Just collapse
> this list if it is hiding the options.
>
> Note also, that if you make a copy of the project, the new project
> will have all the changes as if all were selected and accepted.

Comment: This was extremely helpful, the correct procedure based on this is Ctrl + A then on the top right there is a "Accept/Reject All" option after everything is highlighted!

Comment: It's completely bonkers that they hide it under the track changes context menu...

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a hack: keep the tracking mode on, control-A select the entire document, control-X cut all, and control-P paste all. Now Overleaf will consider the whole document as one single change. Accept it. Turn off tracking mode. Done.